# C++ How to cin a string into a vector and then display the inputs

Tags: c++, string, vector, cin

Im a little stuck on trying to figure out how to let the user enter in several strings and then display the strings when they enter this "*". Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input;

    cout<<"Enter in your shopping list.  Enter in * to indicate you are done"<<endl;

    vector<string> shoppingList();

    while(cin>>input && input != *)
        {
            shoppingList.push_back(input);
        }
    if(cin>>input == *)
    {
        write_vector(shoppingList);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am not C++ expert but do you guys use == or std::string::compare to compare two Strings?

Comment: @KickButtowski yes, `operator==` is for equality check. `compare` is for sorting.

Comment: You were almost right... as well as ravi's tip on defining your `vector`, you just need `...&& input != "*")` and later `if (input == "*") ...`.  That is to say, your "string literals" must be double-quoted.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things wrong in this:-

```
 vector<string> shoppingList();     //This would be treated as function declaration...
```

This should be

```
vector<string> shoppingList;
```

And then

```
if(cin>>input == *)
```

You should take the input in some string and then compare it with "*"

Comment: I am not C++ expert but do you guys use == or std::string::compare to compare two Strings?

Comment: Personal choice. I like to use `compare` which is more C-like (and resembles the `equals` of Java although the return values are very different) but other folk find `==` clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I think  you are looking for this answer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input;

    cout<<"Enter in your shopping list.  Enter in * to indicate you are done"<<endl;

    vector<string> shoppingList;
    while(input != "*")
        {
            cin>>input;
            shoppingList.push_back(input);
        }
    if(input == "*")
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i<(shoppingList.size() -1);i++)
            cout<<shoppingList[i]<<" " ;
    }

    return 0;
}
```